# How to use PowerShell to write a files content to different rows in Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to automate the following manual task, and am struggling with part of it:

1) Open a text file that contains multiple lines containing data.

2) Copy the contents of this file to the clipboard.

3) Open and Excel spreadsheet.

4) Rename the spreadsheet to Test.

5) Paste the contents of the clipboard.

When this is done manually the content is pasted and each line in the text file is inserted as a new row in column A.

Originally the customer wanted all of the file content to be injected into cell A1. I was able to achieve this with the below PowerShell code.

However they have since changed this back to wanting each line of text to go into a separate row in column A.

I cannot figure out how to do this gracefully via the Get-Content method of copying out the text data. I have seen workarounds to this issue whereby Excel opens the text file and copies the text into an intermediate workbook and then into the final workbook.

Could someone please let me know if it's possible to amend my already working code below so that it adds the text to rows in column A rather than to cell A1?

```
# Clear the screen of any previous text.
cls

$ExcelFile="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\Test.xlsx"
$TextFile="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\TestText.txt"
$Content = Get-Content $TextFile -Raw

# Perform operations in Excel based on content of the downloaded file.
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

# For troubleshooting enable the below to view Excel as file is manipulated:
#$Excel.Visible=$true
# Disable Excel alerts. Hash this line out for troubleshooting.
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

# Set up workbook...
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$Data = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$Data.Name = 'Test'

# Insert Data   
$Data.Cells.Item(1,1) = "$Content"

# Format, save and quit excel
$UsedRange = $Data.UsedRange                                                                                              
$UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null
$Workbook.SaveAs("$ExcelFile")
$Excel.Quit()
```

I know that the part I would need to change is as follows, but I'm not sure what to change it to:

```
# Insert Data   
$Data.Cells.Item(1,1) = "$Content"
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need to find the last used row in the sheet and write each line from there:

```
$ExcelFile = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\Test.xlsx"
$TextFile  = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\TestText.txt"

# Perform operations in Excel based on content of the downloaded file.
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

# open the file and select the first worksheet
$WorkBook  = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFile)
$WorkSheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
# get the first unused row
$row = ($WorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows).Count + 1
# fill in the data
Get-Content -Path $TextFile | ForEach-Object {
    $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($row++, 1) = $_
}

# format column A and save the file
$UsedRange = $WorkSheet.UsedRange                                                                                              
$UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null
$WorkBook.Save()

# quit excel and clean up the used COM objects
$Excel.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WorkSheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WorkBook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Theo. This approach worked perfectly. Plus the additional code for the clean up was a bonus!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution would be to read each line in content by  for or foreach loop

in loop, write the line's content into the last row of column A in the excel file.

It's will be something like this

```
foreach($line in $Content){
   $Data.Cells.Item($LastRow,1) = $line


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is much appreciated.